# Create 2 columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have been struggling with this for so long. Hope someone can assist me.
I would like to add 2 columns based on conditions of 3 columns.

```
Quote/Offer|RequiredLoanAmount |QuotationAmount|**Quote Amount**| **Offer Amount**
Quote      |      490000       |       0       |   0            |   0
Pending    |      640000       |     640000    | 640000         |   0
Pending    |      1180000      |     1062000   |   0            | 1062000
Offer      |      2562000      |     2305800   |   0            | 2305800
Quote      |      400000       |     392000    | 392000         |   0
Quote      |      770000       |     770000    | 770000         |   0
Pending    |      425000       |     680000    | 680000         |   0
Pending    |      1580000      |     1500000   |   0            | 1500000
Pending    |      260000       |     239985    |   0            | 239985
Pending    |      285000       |     285000    | 285000         |   0
Pending    |      600000       |     600000    | 600000         |   0
Pending    |      700000       |     700000    | 700000         |   0
Pending    |      1350000      |     1350000   | 1350000        |   0
Offer      |      689000       |     650000    |   0            | 650000
Pending    |      1980000      |     1980000   | 1980000        |   0
Pending    |      960000       |     960000    | 960000         |   0
Offer      |      670000       |     636500    |   0            | 636500
```

When Quote/Offer = Pending or Quote and amount Received - Required Amount >= 0 then it should put the Amount Received in the Quote Amount Column

When Quote/Offer = Pending or Offer and amount Received - Required Amount < 0 then it should put the Amount Received in the Offer Amount Column

The formula in my Excel spreadsheet is as follows:

**For Quote Amount:**

```
=IF(AND(S22="Pending",(Q22-P22)>=0)=TRUE,Q22,IF(S22="Quote",Q22,0))
```

**For Offer Amount**

```
=IF(AND(S22="Pending",(Q22-P22)<0)=TRUE,Q22,IF(S22="Offer",Q22,0))
```

This is what I have tried in SQL:

```
    SELECT *
, CASE
    WHEN [Quote/Offer] = 'Quote' AND QuotationAmount - RequiredLoanAmount >= 0 THEN QuotationAmount
    WHEN [Quote/Offer] = 'Pending' AND QuotationAmount - RequiredLoanAmount < 0 THEN QuotationAmount 
    ELSE 0
END AS QuoteAmount,

CASE
    WHEN [Quote/Offer] = 'Offer' AND QuotationAmount - RequiredLoanAmount > 0 THEN QuotationAmount 
    WHEN [Quote/Offer] = 'Pending' AND QuotationAmount - RequiredLoanAmount < 0 THEN QuotationAmount
    ELSE 0 
END AS OfferAmount

FROM #SubDatePartition
```

I have tried a few other way but this is the closest that I get the the required result.

I would really appreciate the help. Hope this is enough information.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output are the last two columns in the table above. Quote Amount and Offer Amount

Comment: then why you use select all? in this query the rows of all column is greater than the your QuoteAmount column which is use in case

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. I just wanted to make the code shorter and easier to read. Should I include the columns?

Comment: I have changed to query sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(S22="Pending",(Q22-P22)>=0)=TRUE,Q22,IF(S22="Quote",Q22,0))
```

will be equal

```
CASE
WHEN [Quote/Offer] = 'Pending' AND QuotationAmount - RequiredLoanAmount >= 0 THEN QuotationAmount
WHEN [Quote/Offer] = 'Quote' THEN QuotationAmount
ELSE 0
END AS QuoteAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you was putting the multiple conditions of each case in separated `WHEN`'s instead of chaining the conditions with the appropriate `AND/OR` operators (note that `[Quote/Offer] IN ('Pending','Quote')` is equivalent to `([Quote/Offer]='Pending' OR [Quote/Offer]='Quote')`):

```
SELECT [Quote/Offer], RequiredLoanAmount, QuotationAmount,
  CASE WHEN [Quote/Offer] IN ('Pending','Quote') AND QuotationAmount-RequiredLoanAmount>=0
       THEN QuotationAmount ELSE 0
    END AS QuoteAmount,
  CASE WHEN [Quote/Offer] IN ('Pending','Offer') AND QuotationAmount-RequiredLoanAmount<0
       THEN QuotationAmount ELSE 0 
  END AS OfferAmount
FROM #SubDatePartition
```

Comment: Thank you very much